# Getting activity result in OnPause after call to finish()

Tags: android

I'm looking for the accessor version of Activity's setResult(). Imagine getResult() to return a Bundle if a resultCode and Intent have been used in setResult().

The reason for this is by default activities load with the resultCode set to RESULT_CANCELED: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/app/Activity.java#669, and I would like to be able to query the resultCode from the onPause method. This might save a listener for the back button pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just save the `resultCode` to a member variable when you set it and read it back in `onPasuse`?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private int result = RESULT_CANCELLED;
    ...
    // do some stuff
    result = RESULT_OK;
    setResult(result);
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        switch (result) {
        case RESULT_OK:
            // do stuff
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also do some something similar with any `Intent` you use.

You would have to bear in mind that `onPause` will be called any time that your `Activity` is no longer in the foreground, not just when you have set a result and called `finish()`.

Comment: I was hoping to eliminate having to track it with another member variable. After looking through the Android source code further it appears that this is may be the only way to do it.